# Android Security Testing and Tools Clarifications

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-assessment

I'm new to cybersecurity and learning about pen testing Android security. I need tools for this. I found a website with a list of 75 tools (https://gbhackers.com/android-security-penetration-testing/). But I'm not sure if they're all meant for this kind of testing.

This got me thinking about what Android security testing really means. I read on Wikipedia that

> A penetration test, colloquially known as a pentest or ethical
> hacking, is an authorized simulated cyberattack on a computer system,
> performed to evaluate the security of the system; this is not to be
> confused with a vulnerability assessment

This definition raises a question: Is a vulnerability assessment considered a subset or a distinct form of penetration testing?

So, what's the basic idea behind testing Android security, and can I trust the tools listed on that website? **Note**: This question is **NOT** about **product recommendations**.

Comment: This type of comment is neither productive, nor makes me want to answer your question. Have you tried searching for articles? Does this help you understand the concepts better: https://www.veracode.com/security/vulnerability-assessment-and-penetration-testing https://purplesec.us/learn/vulnerability-assessment-vs-penetration-testing/ ? Regarding the tools, what do you mean about "trust"? That there are free of viruses? or that they work effectively? But unless someone actually tried them, it is difficult to answer...